# Database connection initialisation failed in Umbraco

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, umbraco

I keep getting this issue are there any error logs I can look at to see what is happening?

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using? This is usually caused by incorrect database settings in your web.config, or by problems reaching your DB server.

Comment: 4.7.1 - I can login to SQL server Management Studio with the username and pass

Comment: is it during the install or has this been working?

Comment: during the install, I can only assume it was a problem with the binaries or permissions as I made an exact replica of another site and it worked. The only problem is the uselessness of the error message, this is not really very helpful, as you are just guessing what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SQL express? If so the database may be in autoshutdown mode. You should find any errors in the app log. Is the app pool for umbraco allowed to connect to the database? This error is often associate with security, so giving a "you need to enable so and so" would be of great assistance to a hacker. Check permissions for the app pool account. Check if you have Mcaffee installed - it has a habit of denying access. Try connecting using SQL authentication to see if its a role thing. Copy and paste your connection string from SSMS connection dialog to the app web config. Typoz are a given. At least you now know why the message is usless! 
PS there is an article with screen shots on an umbraco IIS install, it might serve as a cross reference http://www.ava.co.uk/support/faq/umbraco/install-umbraco-4042-windows-server-2008-iis-6-sql-2008-r2.aspx